# What does it mean to deinitialize an object?

Tags: c++

Wen a destructor is called for a particular object in C++, the destructor first deinitializes the object and then deletes the object.

What I don't get is what it means to _de_initialize an object. What does it mean, and what happens?

Comment: What article/book/person are you going from? The standard has no mention of "deinitializes" (or "uninitializes").

Comment: In C++ the deinitializer is exactly the same thing as the deconstructor - a wrong, misused term.

Comment: It might mean for example that you can clear arrays used for sensitive data like passwords before deleting them. It's not a term found in the language standard.

Comment: @ddriver In this case clearly not. OP has clearly distinguished 'destructor' from 'deinitialization'. In fact he hasn't used 'deinitializer' at all. Not a useful comment.

Comment: @EJP - judging by the title of the question, I am still willing to put my money on a misplaced term.

Comment: Flag for Programmers.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you were rewriting `std::string`. It's managing a `char` array that it dynamically allocated. When the string object is deleted, you want the `char` array to get freed as well. The destructor is the place to do that.

Or perhaps you were making something to represent a Windows `HANDLE` or UNIX file descriptor. When your object is deleted, you probably want to close that handle or file descriptor. Again, the destructor is the place to do that.

In general, the destructor is the place to release the resources associated with that object, whatever those resources might be.

Answer (score 2):

The word deinitialization is never mentioned in the standard. As for what it would mean, it would mean that the object releases any file handles, frees up resources, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion may be due to some libraries out there featuring an `init()` method enforced by the API that is typically called on the last line of the constructor, after all dynamic data and possible connections are handled.

IMO, this is just a part of the object construction, and the `init()` method is mostly a way to clear up the code a bit, because no one like a wall of code for a constructor. I frequently create `initGUI()` and `initConnections()` methods to keep the constructor clean.

In case where de-initialization is needed it is a good idea to do it in the reverse order. I mean, if the initialization was the last line of the constructor, it mostly likely should also be the first line of the destructor:

```
Instantiation
   Constructor 
      Initialization
         Usage
      De-initialization
   Destructor
Deletion
```